# TimeStamp value trimming while retriving from oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc, struts

i have the data in Oracle DB its a TimeStamp filed when i try to retrive it through java program it's trimming the nano seconds value and AM/PM .

Like how in DB :- `02-03-11 01:55:10.000000000 AM`
While Fetching `rs.getTimeStamp()` - `02-03-11 01:55:10.0`

i should retrive the complete time .

Please provide a solution .

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

You're only showing a *string* representation, which is trimming off most of the insignificant zeroes. I see no sign of actual *information* loss here. (It looks like a 24-hour string representation, so the AM is implicit.)

I suggest you try with a timestamp which has a subsecond value of (say) 123456789 and see whether you can get *that* back correctly. If so, there's definitely no issue.

It's important to differentiate between the *inherent* data (an instant in time) and a *string representation* of that data ("02-03-11 01:55:10.000000000 AM" or "02-03-11 01:55:10.0").

Answer (score 0):

try forcing oracle to provide the nano seconds in the returned data set as string by specifing FF in the data/time format:

```
SELECT to_char(TIME_STAMP_FIELD,'dd-Mon-yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF') from TABLE_NAME
```